# Merging Models with Keras' Functional API

Tags: python, merge, keras, keras-layer

I am new to deep learning and am teaching myself some NLP concepts. I am trying to understand this by working on Quora's sentence similarity scoring model as explained in this excellent tutorial [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/duplicate-quora-question-abhishek-thakur/).

The code is from a while back and in trying to get it to run on a new dataset, I figured that the model merging API had been deprecated. I have been sitting and struggling for a long time to merge the models (since I don't understand the complexities too much).

Could anyone please help me verify if I have converted this the right way? The main question I have is the input sequences have been padded to a `max_len` of 40, so does that mean I have to specify an input layer with a shape of 40?

**OLD CODE ON SITE:**

```
tk = text.Tokenizer(nb_words=200000)

max_len = 40
tk.fit_on_texts(list(data.question1.values) + list(data.question2.values.astype(str)))
x1 = tk.texts_to_sequences(data.question1.values)
x1 = sequence.pad_sequences(x1, maxlen=max_len)

x2 = tk.texts_to_sequences(data.question2.values.astype(str))
x2 = sequence.pad_sequences(x2, maxlen=max_len)

word_index = tk.word_index

ytrain_enc = np_utils.to_categorical(y)

embeddings_index = {}
f = open('data/glove.840B.300d.txt')
for line in tqdm(f):
    values = line.split()
    word = values[0]
    coefs = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32')
    embeddings_index[word] = coefs
f.close()

print('Found %s word vectors.' % len(embeddings_index))

embedding_matrix = np.zeros((len(word_index) + 1, 300))
for word, i in tqdm(word_index.items()):
    embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
    if embedding_vector is not None:
        embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector

max_features = 200000
filter_length = 5
nb_filter = 64
pool_length = 4

model = Sequential()
print('Build model...')

model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(Embedding(len(word_index) + 1,
                     300,
                     weights=[embedding_matrix],
                     input_length=40,
                     trainable=False))

model1.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(300, activation='relu')))
model1.add(Lambda(lambda x: K.sum(x, axis=1), output_shape=(300,)))

model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(Embedding(len(word_index) + 1,
                     300,
                     weights=[embedding_matrix],
                     input_length=40,
                     trainable=False))

model2.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(300, activation='relu')))
model2.add(Lambda(lambda x: K.sum(x, axis=1), output_shape=(300,)))

model3 = Sequential()
model3.add(Embedding(len(word_index) + 1,
                     300,
                     weights=[embedding_matrix],
                     input_length=40,
                     trainable=False))
model3.add(Convolution1D(nb_filter=nb_filter,
                         filter_length=filter_length,
                         border_mode='valid',
                         activation='relu',
                         subsample_length=1))
model3.add(Dropout(0.2))

model3.add(Convolution1D(nb_filter=nb_filter,
                         filter_length=filter_length,
                         border_mode='valid',
                         activation='relu',
                         subsample_length=1))

model3.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model3.add(Dropout(0.2))

model3.add(Dense(300))
model3.add(Dropout(0.2))
model3.add(BatchNormalization())

model4 = Sequential()
model4.add(Embedding(len(word_index) + 1,
                     300,
                     weights=[embedding_matrix],
                     input_length=40,
                     trainable=False))
model4.add(Convolution1D(nb_filter=nb_filter,
                         filter_length=filter_length,
                         border_mode='valid',
                         activation='relu',
                         subsample_length=1))
model4.add(Dropout(0.2))

model4.add(Convolution1D(nb_filter=nb_filter,
                         filter_length=filter_length,
                         border_mode='valid',
                         activation='relu',
                         subsample_length=1))

model4.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model4.add(Dropout(0.2))

model4.add(Dense(300))
model4.add(Dropout(0.2))
model4.add(BatchNormalization())
model5 = Sequential()
model5.add(Embedding(len(word_index) + 1, 300, input_length=40, dropout=0.2))
model5.add(LSTM(300, dropout_W=0.2, dropout_U=0.2))

model6 = Sequential()
model6.add(Embedding(len(word_index) + 1, 300, input_length=40, dropout=0.2))
model6.add(LSTM(300, dropout_W=0.2, dropout_U=0.2))

merged_model = Sequential()
merged_model.add(Merge([model1, model2, model3, model4, model5, model6], mode='concat'))
merged_model.add(BatchNormalization())

merged_model.add(Dense(300))
merged_model.add(PReLU())
merged_model.add(Dropout(0.2))
merged_model.add(BatchNormalization())

merged_model.add(Dense(300))
merged_model.add(PReLU())
merged_model.add(Dropout(0.2))
merged_model.add(BatchNormalization())

merged_model.add(Dense(300))
merged_model.add(PReLU())
merged_model.add(Dropout(0.2))
merged_model.add(BatchNormalization())

merged_model.add(Dense(300))
merged_model.add(PReLU())
merged_model.add(Dropout(0.2))
merged_model.add(BatchNormalization())

merged_model.add(Dense(300))
merged_model.add(PReLU())
merged_model.add(Dropout(0.2))
merged_model.add(BatchNormalization())

merged_model.add(Dense(1))
merged_model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
```

What I have till now (from the architecture specified, and in general):

**MY ATTEMPT AT MERGING USING THE FUNCTIONAL API:**

```
tk = text.Tokenizer(nb_words=200000, filters='!"#$%&*+,/;<>?@\^`{|}~')

max_len = 40
tk.fit_on_texts(list(data.log1.values) + list(data.log2.values.astype(str)))
x1 = tk.texts_to_sequences(data.log1.values)
x1 = sequence.pad_sequences(x1, maxlen=max_len)

x2 = tk.texts_to_sequences(data.log2.values.astype(str))
x2 = sequence.pad_sequences(x2, maxlen=max_len)

word_index = tk.word_index

ytrain_enc = np_utils.to_categorical(y)

embeddings_index = {}
f = open('data/glove.840B.300d.txt')
for line in tqdm(f):
    values = line.split()
    word = values[0]
    coefs = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32')
    embeddings_index[word] = coefs
f.close()

print('Found %s word vectors.' % len(embeddings_index))

embedding_matrix = np.zeros((len(word_index) + 1, 300))
for word, i in tqdm(word_index.items()):
    embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
    if embedding_vector is not None:
        embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector

max_features = 200000
filter_length = 5
nb_filter = 64
pool_length = 4

input_layer = Input(shape=(40,))
print('Build model...')

# Converting everything to Keras' functional API
# We don't need model1 = Sequential() since the functional API specifies this
# implicitly
model1 = Embedding(len(word_index) + 1, 300, weights=[embedding_matrix],
                   input_length=40, trainable=False)(input_layer)
model1 = TimeDistributed(Dense(300, activation='relu'))(model1)
model1 = Lambda(lambda x: K.sum(x, axis=1), output_shape=(300,))(model1)

model2 = Embedding(len(word_index) + 1, 300, weights=[embedding_matrix],
                   input_length=40, trainable=False)(input_layer)
model2 = TimeDistributed(Dense(300, activation='relu'))(model2)
model2 = Lambda(lambda x: K.sum(x, axis=1), output_shape=(300,))(model2)

model3 = Embedding(len(word_index) + 1, 300, weights=[embedding_matrix],
                   input_length=40, trainable=False)(input_layer)
model3 = Convolution1D(nb_filter=nb_filter, filter_length=filter_length,
                       border_mode='valid', activation='relu',
                       subsample_length=1)(model3)
model3 = Dropout(0.2)(model3)
model3 = Convolution1D(nb_filter=nb_filter, filter_length=filter_length,
                       border_mode='valid', activation='relu',
                       subsample_length=1)(model3)
model3 = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(model3)
model3 = Dropout(0.2)(model3)
model3 = Dense(300)(model3)
model3 = Dropout(0.2)(model3)
model3 = BatchNormalization()(model3)

model4 = Embedding(len(word_index) + 1, 300, weights=[embedding_matrix],
                   input_length=40, trainable=False)(input_layer)
model4 = Convolution1D(nb_filter=nb_filter, filter_length=filter_length, border_mode='valid',
                       activation='relu', subsample_length=1)(model4)
model4 = Dropout(0.2)(model4)
model4 = Convolution1D(nb_filter=nb_filter, filter_length=filter_length, border_mode='valid',
                       activation='relu', subsample_length=1)(model4)
model4 = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(model4)
model4 = Dropout(0.2)(model4)
model4 = Dense(300)(model4)
model4 = Dropout(0.2)(model4)
model4 = BatchNormalization()(model4)

model5 = Embedding(len(word_index) + 1, 300, input_length=40, dropout=0.2)(input_layer)
model5 = LSTM(300, dropout_W=0.2, dropout_U=0.2)(model5)

model6 = Embedding(len(word_index) + 1, 300, input_length=40, dropout=0.2)(input_layer)
model6 = LSTM(300, dropout_W=0.2, dropout_U=0.2)(model6)


merged_model = concatenate([model1, model2, model3, model4, model5, model6])

merged_model = BatchNormalization()(merged_model)
merged_model = Dense(300)(merged_model)
merged_model = PReLU()(merged_model)
merged_model = Dropout(0.2)(merged_model)

merged_model = BatchNormalization()(merged_model)
merged_model = Dense(300)(merged_model)
merged_model = PReLU()(merged_model)
merged_model = Dropout(0.2)(merged_model)

merged_model = BatchNormalization()(merged_model)
merged_model = Dense(300)(merged_model)
merged_model = PReLU()(merged_model)
merged_model = Dropout(0.2)(merged_model)

merged_model = BatchNormalization()(merged_model)
merged_model = Dense(300)(merged_model)
merged_model = PReLU()(merged_model)
merged_model = Dropout(0.2)(merged_model)

merged_model = BatchNormalization()(merged_model)
merged_model = Dense(300)(merged_model)
merged_model = PReLU()(merged_model)
merged_model = Dropout(0.2)(merged_model)

merged_model = BatchNormalization()(merged_model)
# merged_model = Dense(1)(merged_model)
# merged_model = Activation('sigmoid')(merged_model)

predictions = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(merged_model)
model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=predictions)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('weights.h5', monitor='val_acc', save_best_only=True, verbose=2)
model.fit([x1, x2, x1, x2, x1, x2], y=y, batch_size=384, nb_epoch=200,
                 verbose=1, validation_split=0.1, shuffle=True, callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

I am not sure if I have done things perfectly right, so I am asking for someone to verify it out here. Apparently, the training time takes 10-15 hours and I really don't want it to error out halfway through because I missed something. Having someone verify this might be a quicker way to do this before I run it.

Also, when giving suggestions, please do keep in mind I, in all probability will not know what you are talking about since this is really new to me (kindly dumb it down for me).

Thank you in advance for your help.